# CDH4.x : Installation hangs there

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I've downloaded `cloudera-manager-installer.bin` from CDH's official site. But when I trying to install it, the program hangs at 40% progress.

The installation log looks like this:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn
 * rpmforge: ftp.riken.jp
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloudera-manager-server.x86_64 0:4.8.2-1.cm482.p0.101.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cloudera-manager-daemons = 4.8.2 for package: cloudera-manager-server-4.8.2-1.cm482.p0.101.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloudera-manager-daemons.x86_64 0:4.8.2-1.cm482.p0.101.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                 Arch   Version                  Repository        Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 cloudera-manager-server x86_64 4.8.2-1.cm482.p0.101.el6 cloudera-manager 7.7 k
Installing for dependencies:
 cloudera-manager-daemons
                         x86_64 4.8.2-1.cm482.p0.101.el6 cloudera-manager 148 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 148 M
Installed size: 203 M
Downloading Packages:
```

I can access `archive.cloudera.com` from my server.

How can I deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
sudo unmount cm_processes
sudo rm -Rf /var/run/cloudera*
```

Doing it solved this for me.